# How to Display Mobile Layout of Power BI Report in Web Application when embedding is done using Secure Embed option?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have created a Power BI report and embedded it in a web application using Secure Embed option that provides an iframe. Now I need to display Mobile Layout of this report when my web application opens in a mobile device.

I am not using Power BI Embedded.

Comment: Mobile layout is shown in Power BI Mobile apps only.

Comment: Or with JavaScript API in Powe BI Embedded.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to view in mobile layout if you are using secure embed option unless modifying iframe to mobile layout width and height.
But using embedded you can use javascript API to acheive the required result

```
let embedConfig = {
    ...
    settings: {
        layoutType: models.LayoutType.MobilePortrait
    }
};
```

References:
https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/mobile